# How can I delete user made by django rest_auth in admin page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-users, django-rest-auth

I made a user using rest_auth. And I want to delete those users from the django_admin page. But when I try to delete it, the following error occurs.

> OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/ no such table: allauth_socialaccount

Through the search, I got results to put 'allauth.socialaccount' in INSTALLED_APPS, but this didn't help me. how can I solve it ?

Comment: Can you try migrating your database?

Comment: did you run migrate after adding allauth.socialaccount to the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I can't believe I made this basic mistake.... thanks bro